# what is the es6 fat arrow equivalent to a es5 function declaration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

With ES5 I can declare either a function declaration or expression, depending on what I need.

```
function es5FunctionDeclaration() {
  return 'I am an es5 function declaration';
}

var es5FunctionExpression = function() {
  return 'I am an es5 function expression';
}
```

With the ES6 fat arrow, it is common to create a function expression like this...

```
const es6FunctionExpression = () => {
  return 'I am an es6 function expression';
}
```

But I haven't find a way to do a function declaration with a fat arrow, perhaps it is not possible.

```
// es6FunctionDeclarationWithFatArrow ??
```

Comment: There is no way....

Comment: any particular reason why?

Comment: Because you can't name an arrow function...

Comment: Function declarations are hoisted with values. Hoisting is not considered good. You can reassign a variable declared with `var` due to hoisting. So to ES6 was designed to remove all those problems. So there was no point to add same function declaration. `var` could have been totally removed from ES6 but its wasn't(because the already made programs may fail due to that).

Comment: All 3 have different syntax and subtly behave differently. ES6 function expressions are not equivalent to ES5 function expressions.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  This sounds like an AB problem.

Comment: @zero298 Just trying to get a better understanding of why this is the case. Maheer Ali mentioned hoisting can introduce unexpected bugs and this helps solve that problem

Comment: I think the reason is that there is no real need for it. `f() =>` instead of `const f = () =>` seems nice, but I am not aware of any languages that use anything similar

Comment: Maheer is just mixing up vaguely related and heavily opinionated stuff here with `var` and hoisting. I've never seen those straw-man hoisting-related bugs. It's just that some developers don't get it so they'll have trouble reading the code, and since code should be written for developers, you may want to spare those inexperienced ones the head scratching. Reassignment to `var`s is not a hoisting issue — or an issue at all, it's a **variable** after all. ES6 just gives you the choice of declaring constants instead. Doesn't mean variables are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

To declare functions in ES6 you can do it via:

```
const functionName = () => {};
```

Or you can do it via the `function` keyword:

```
function functionName() {}
```

And, if you're creating ES6 classes you don't create functions but methods:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {}
  method1() {}
  method2() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The definition of an arrow function is here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions

```
ArrowFunction[In, Yield] :
    ArrowParameters[?Yield] [no LineTerminator here] => ConciseBody[?In]
ArrowParameters[Yield] :
    BindingIdentifier[?Yield] CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList[?Yield]
ConciseBody[In] :
    [lookahead ≠ { ] AssignmentExpression[?In] { FunctionBody }
```

What this means in English, is that an arrow function can only be declared like so `args => {}` and that's it. As you say, you can bind it to a variable with, for example, `const func = args => {}` or by passing it as an argument to another function, but there's no way. Indeed, passing an arrow function as an argument was one of the major reasons it was created (because of binding `this`). See [lexical this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/f0d591b6502c080b92e18fc470432af8144db610/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#user-content-lexical-this) (and the [appendix](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/f0d591b6502c080b92e18fc470432af8144db610/scope%20%26%20closures/apC.md))

As @MaheerAli has mentioned, arrow functions neatly avoids function [hoisting](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch4.md) which may be surprising behaviour.

ES6 does have some ways to declare functions in a shorter manner, such as within objects:

```
const obj = {
    func() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all hoisting is not a good/useful phenomena and function declarations are hoisted with value. The problem of not throwing error even declaring a variable twice is also due to hoisting.

ES6 was designed to remove all those problems. So there was no point to have the same function declaration again added as a new feature to cause problems again.

The is same like why in ES6 `let` and `const` can't be redeclared or how we could make `let` and `const` like `var`

Comment: Hoisting may be confusing for some, but it is most certainly not *wrong* or *useless*. Indeed, many developers appreciate that it allows them to leave the implementation details at the bottom of a function and the logic (with `return`s) at the top. Besides, a modern IDE like VSCode will show you clearly what's going on.

Comment: @Touffy There might be some uses of hoisting but in general its not useful. As I explained in answer the redeclaration of variables declared with `var`(which is considered a big issue) is due to hoisting.

Comment: @Touffy The variables declared with `let` and `const` also hoists but in a different way so its not harmful. I am specifically talking about hoisting before ES6

Comment: Variable hoisting is less useful because the initialisation is not hoisted (and *that* is easier to misunderstand). Functions do not have that issue, and hoisting them can even be necessary in some cases like mutual recursion.

Comment: `let` and `const` do not hoist in any way. They can be written lexically before the declaration, but not actually used at runtime before the declaration happens. That's one of the differences with `var` (the "temporal dead zone"). You're obviously just repeating what Crockford has been claiming for decades calling stuff "harmful", but that's just an opinion, not an explanation or in any way a valid answer to the question.